# Passive of modal verb "dare"

Tags: modal-verbs, passive-voice, semi-modals

What would be the passive of the following sentence?

> You dare not talk to her.

Also,  is it right to say "you dare not talk to her" at all?

Comment: It's OK to say _You dare not talk to her_. But this is not a transitive sentence, so it doesn't have a passive transform. Sorry.

Comment: Ok,  what would be passive if :       he must talk to her

Comment: That's not transitive, either. "Transitive" means there is a direct object. You need to have a direct object in the original sentence, because that's what becomes the new subject in the passive transform. There's no direct object in _He must talk to her_ -- and before you ask, _He should/can/may/might/would talk to her_ are also intransitive, because _talk_ is intransitive.

Comment: Oh, and I notice that you are linking the passive to the modal. That's part of the problem. Modal auxiliary verbs don't passivize; they're auxiliary verbs. Only main, transitive, verbs can passivize. Auxiliaries get carried along; so the passive of _He can see her_ (which is transitive) is _She can be seen by him_. It's the _see_ that passivizes, not the modal _can_.

Comment: @JohnLawler whilst I appreciate that 'talk' is not, nor can be transitive, isn't the OP speaking about 'dare'? If I say 'he dares all', is 'all' not a direct object, and the passive 'All is dared by him'?

Comment: @ws 2  in my opinion dares in "He dares all" is acting as a main verb and not as a modal verb.  Also shouldn't it be "all are dared by him".

Comment: @WS2: That's not the example sentence. OP calls it modal, and is using _dare_ as a modal auxiliary, properly, in a negative polarity environment. This is an auxiliary use, not the transitive sense of _dare_ that takes as object what might be lost by taking the risk.

Comment: @john sir,  is it right:      active :I must do it.  Passive : it must be done by me.

Comment: @user92268: Yes, that's right. Auxiliaries of whatever kind simply attach to the main verb in their usual positions. The passive auxiliary _be_ is the last one in the chain, directly preceding the past participle form of the main verb. All you have to do is change that end of the verb phrase and make the old object the new subject. The _by_-phrase is optional, and usually omitted. Details in the [Verb Phrase Study Guide](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf)

Comment: @JohnLawler I didn’t read your comment before I posted my answer, but I’m wondering if the reason that alone of the modals, *dare* doesn’t seem to be able to apply to a passive infinitive with swapped subject/object without changing the sentence’s meaning is because it seems to lack the customary deontic-epistemic duality. You can do it with things like *will* and *must*, but not *dare*. Yet there are fine sentences with modal *dare* + passive inf. like “I dare not be distracted by noise.” But you can’t flip that one to “Noise dare not distract me.” Weird.

Comment: Whenever you use a modal and a negative together, odd phenomena are possible. And they're excessively idiomatic. _Dare_ only has a deontic sense, since it refers to emotions. The question is -- **whose** emotions? Normally it would be the subject's, but if you passivize, you got a different subject and that doesn't always work. As for _I dare not be distracted_, what it means is _I dare not allow myself to be distracted_, where the passive is in the complement.

Answer (score 3):

## Modals as Defective Verbs

Modals are considered neither transitive nor intransitive.  Modals just change some aspect of the principal verb. This is normally either some aspect that says something about the simple “futureness” or probability, or else instead something about how the world is supposed to be but is not.

Not being transitive themselves, they cannot transfer any “action” to an object for that object to be then used as a subject in a passive construction.

As verbs go, modals are formally ***defective***.  They have no *to*-infinitive, no participles, they can’t be used in imperatives, &c&c&c — really nothing else that a verb is **supposed** to have to be a proper verb.

Since they have no participles, modals cannot themselves be turned into passive forms: you need a “passive past participle” for that, and they have no participles.

Their defective state is why you cannot take a modal like *must* and make of it forms like **musting* or **musted* or even **musts*.  That means nothing can ever *“be *musted”*.  (Well, not in the obligatory way; there are other verbs named *must* which are not modals, but they don’t matter here.)

### Modal *dare*

As with *must*’s lack of needed forms, the same is true with *dare* ***when it it is used modally***.  These are modal uses:

- He **must say** nothing to her.
- He **dare say** nothing to her. (notice for future that it reads *he dare*, not an inflected *he dares*)

The principal verb is *say*, with *must* or *dare* just along for the ride.  Neither *dare* nor *must* themselves have a direct object for you to scoop up and use for a subject in those sentences.  *Nothing* is the direct object of *say*, not of *dare* or of *must*.

This is a modal use because it didn’t inflect for the third-person present singular.  When it does, it is not a modal use:

- He **dares to tell** her of his past.

Now it is on different from something like:

- He **hopes to tell** her of his past.

### Non-modal *dare*

On the other hand, *dare* also enjoys a non-modal existence, and here it can be either intransitive or transitive.  And when transitive, if it has an object, then you can flip it.

- He **dared** anything for her sake.

That one has a direct object for its inflected, non-modal use of transitive *dare*, so you can make that one passive:

- Anything **was dared** by him for her sake.

However, I dare say that that one is not the kind of *dare* you are talking about, although the first one in this sentence was.

### Applying modals to passive infinitives

There is another way of looking at it, however.  It might well be better if I durst<sup>1</sup> say nothing, but if I didn’t, someone else would.  So I might as well be the one to make — and break — the case for the tempting but ultimately unworkable alternative.

That’s because there is still a way to use modals with passives: by factoring them out first.

That way you can still reverse the subject and object by taking the past participle of the main verb.

However, instead of inflecting *be*, you use its bare infinitive form and re-apply the original modal to the resulting ***passive infinitive***, so something like *“be WHATEVERed”*.

Some of these work alright:

- He **will explain** everything to her.
- Everything **will be explained** by him to her.

or

- He **will talk** to her.
- She **will be talked** to by him.

or

- He **might call** her.
- She **might be called** by him.

Those aren’t too bad, just wordy.

### But not with *dare*

But now consider pulling that stunt with *dare*. I’ve prefixed the resulting transformations with a funny “<sup>**?**</sup>” sigil to indicate my suspicion that they won’t fly.

- He **dare tell** her nothing.
- <sup>?</sup> Nothing **dare be told** her by him.

or

- He **dare not call** her.
- <sup>?</sup> She **dare not be called** by him.

See how that just doesn’t really work?  You can’t transfer modal *dare* like that to a passive infinitive, because once you’ve done that, it wants to attribute the “daringness” of the matter to the wrong party altogether.

I do not recommend it. I ***seriously*** do not recommend it.

Curiously, this doesn’t mean that you can never use *dare* with passive infinitives. You certainly can:

- I **dare not be distracted** by the construction noise.

However, just as before, you cannot invert that one, this time from passive to active, without the whole sentence falling apart:

- *The construction noise **dare not distract** me.

Ok sure, you can say it, but it is meaningless. It certainly does not mean the same thing as the original did.

### Other semi-modals

You may have the same problem you have with *dare* with the other semi-modals, *need* and *ought*, which work like *must* but perhaps not so strongly.

Since those two work like *must*, here first is *must* used epistemically:

- He **must know** that already.
- That **must be known** by him  already.

Whereas this is *must* used deontically:

- He **must not call** her.
- She **must not be called** by him.

Here is modal *need*:

- He **need not call** her.
- She **need not be called** by him.

And here is modal *ought*:

- He **ought not call** her.
- She **ought not be called** by him.

Those ones you might get away with.  Maybe. They sound pretty awful, but  the duty/obligation sense just might survive being transferred from one party to the other with the passive transformation, at least with *ought*.

### Failure of [Deontic–Epistemic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_modality#Epistemic_vs._deontic_modality) Bimodal Duality in Modal *dare*

Perhaps this difference is because *ought* can be used either epistemically or deontically just like any other full-fledged modal can.

I’m not sure that modal *need* can be used both ways.

And I am pretty sure that modal *dare* does **not** enjoy a bimodal existence at all — which makes it **especially** weird for a modal, since they should all be able to go both ways.

Modals should also not have past tenses (backshifting aside), which is another of *dare*’s funny old quirks.  Watch:

- I **dare mention** nothing of this to my children; they just aren’t ready for it.
- Yesterday, I **dared mention** nothing of this to my children; they just weren’t ready for it.
- I **have never dared mention** any of this to my children; I’ve never wanted them to know.

There we’re inflecting *dare* into a past-tense form, yet using it with a bare infinitive instead of with a *to*-infinitive as if it were some sort of ordinary catenative verb.

You can’t use it as a modal imperatively:

- *Dare dream great things!

But if you stick in a *to*-infinitive, now you can:

- Dare to dream great things!

## Summary

I don’t think that with modal *dare*, you can sensibly get away with swapping subject and object and then use it on a passive infinitive.

Unfortunately, I have no explanation for **why** that path seems blocked. I am no expert, but it truly feels to me like there is **something** about modal *dare* that simply will not allow it to be applied to the resulting passive infinitive once you’ve swapped subject and object.

My only guess is that even when it’s used in a modal-like way, *dare* is saying much more about its subject than about its following verb. If its semantics apply to the subject, then when you try to invert subject–object to either passifize or depassifize the clause, then you’re applying those semantics to the **wrong party**, and so now the meaning changes or falls apart entirely.

_________

<sub>1. *Durst* being the archaic past tense of *dare*, which today survives only in dialect and in older literature.</sub>

Comment: Your comment to John's interesting. I think it's because there's some kind of control going on. Modals are normally associated with raising verbs. *Dare* seems to have some control-like properties.  *He dare __ ask her* is akin to *He dare **himself** ask her*. Where the ID of that 'gap' is governed by *he*. Compare with *She dare __ be asked by him*, which is like *She dare **herself** be asked by him*. The governed bits filled in with bold words also function kinda like DO's. So, they are like *I persuaded her to punch Bob* which isn't the same as *I persuaded Bob to be punched by her*.

Comment: .. but that's just a shot in the dark after few minutes thought.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to put a modal verb in the passive voice.  What's the passive voice of "you must not talk to her"?

Answer (score 0):

To translate into the passive based on the verb 'dare' you would say: "Talking to her was not dared (by you)". An alternative transformation based on the verb 'talk' results in "You dare not have her talked to (by you)", though it's a clumsy sentence with slightly different implications from the original.

Comment: If I consider 'talk to her' as a single entity then dare becomes a main verb and the passive would be 'talk to her is not dared by you' or should I use 'talking to her' in place of 'talk to her' if I want to consider it as a single work.

Comment: The correct form is what I wrote in the answer.